# display certain values mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I have a dilemma with one of my SELECTS that I use in mySQL DB.
Firstly this is how it looks : 
[image: This]

My select is supposed to extract all the users and count each their prezente , when I use this select instead of taking all my users I get this :

```
SELECT users1.id,users1.Nume, COUNT(pontaj.prezente)
FROM users1, pontaj
WHERE users1.id = pontaj.id
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a GROUP BY clause to your query. Also replace the old join syntax using WHERE clause with recommended JOIN / ON syntax.

```
SELECT users1.id,users1.Nume, COUNT(pontaj.prezente)
    FROM users1
    INNER JOIN  pontaj
    ON users1.id = pontaj.id 
 GROUP BY users1.id,users1.Nume
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a group by clause meaning at the end of the SQL add

```
group by users1.Nume
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT users1.id, users1.Nume, COUNT(pontaj.prezente) over (partition by users1.id)
FROM users1
INNER JOIN pontaj ON users1.id = pontaj.id
```

This is an alternative if you don't want to use the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

pontaj.prezente is an INT; perhaps you want SUM(pontaj.prezente) ??